# session replication using AWS tomcat and RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds, tomcat8

I'm having an issue in session replication. I'm using tomcat instance in AWS and RDS MYSql. We have a plan of storing the cookie session in the RDS instead of clustering the tomcat instances. I have two tomcat instances in two different zones and the tomcat instance is having a docker container which is application container (1 container in each instance). When the user logged into the container, I could see that the session is stored in the DB, but I'm making one of the docker containers down, user should be logged in using the cookies available in the RDS MySQL. But when I make one docker container down (where the user is logged in), the second tomcat instance should use the cookies from the MySQL and the user should be logged in without any issue. But the user is logged out all the time when I'm stopping the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

That means your ELB keeps track of which instances it has previously re-directed the users to, and again, re-routes the request to the same instance. You need to disable sticky sessions on the ELB and instead use Sticky Session on your applications, so the tomcat application decides which session to use rather than the ELB itself. Please read the AWS ELB docs for the step by step instructions.

Comment: Its redirecting me to the second instance, when the first instance/docker container is down. But I have to close the browser and reopen it again, and then it shows me the login page of the application. Ultimately, the second instance has to use the cookies present in the DB to keep the session up running.